# Unable to create react app : npm stuck at "found 0 vulnerabilities"

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a react app after passing the command create-react-app app-name the npm stops at found 0 vulnerabilities. However, my directory has been created with 2 files package.json and package-lock.json and a folder node-modules.

Comment: What is the command that you run?

Comment: i think uninstall and reinstall create-react-app can help...